# Socket.io removes some data of my javascript Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, socket.io

I'm facing a problem with data I am sending from a Nodejs server to the client interface using Socket.io

Here is my code on the server side :

```js
socket.emit('message', {
  op : 'sort',
  ...
  wallsData : config.wallsData,
});
```

And below is the output of `config.wallsData`.

```js
{ Bamboo: [ [ 1, 2 ], 'classic' ],
  'Face à Face 1': [ [ 2, 3, 4 ], 'chrono' ],
  'Big Cheese': [ [ 1, 3, 2 ], 'classic' ],
  Detonator: [ [ 1, 2 ], 'classic' ],
  'Twister Face Nord': [ [ 4 ], 'classic' ],
  'Twister Face Sud': [ [ 2 ], 'classic' ],
  'Face à Face 2': [ [ 2, 3, 4 ], 'chrono' ] 
}
```

These data are retrieved from an API, but I could not achieve to get it 'normalized'.
First question : is it important to get all the object keys wrapped in simple quotes before sending it with socket.io ?

On the client side when I receive the data, the content of wallsData is different as follow (printed in chrome console):

```js
{
Bamboo: [[2], "classic"]
Big Cheese: [[1], "classic"]
Detonator: [[], "classic"]
Face à Face 1: [[], "chrono"]
Face à Face 2: [[2,3,4], "chrono"]
Twister Face Nord: [[], "classic"]
Twister Face Sud: [[], "classic"]
}
```

Absolutely no changes is made to the data in between these two steps. I can't figure out what empties or reduce the arrays of integers...

I suspected the object keys with accent to make some fuzzy things, but the data altered are not strictly corresponding to these keys.

Thank you for your help

Cheers

Comment: As a workaround, try to `JSON.stringify(config.wallsData)` server-side, then `JSON.parse()` it client-side ?

Comment: I had tried this also and get ```Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)...``` which matchs with the line where I call JSON.parse on the wallsData on client side. Thanks

Comment: If you get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1` it's because you are trying to JSON.parse something else than a String value. Perhaps you should try to add single quotes to wrap-up your server response : `JSON.parse("'" + response.wallsData + "'")`

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, I ended to find out what was going wrong. Everything was fine about the socket, I was getting confused with method called on an object in a loop. The object reference was the same each time i get into the loop...